# LINQ to SQL in and not in

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

What is  `in` and `not in` equals in [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL)?

For example

```
select * from table in ( ...)
and 
select * from table not in (..)
```

What is equal to the above statement in LINQ to SQL?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You use, `where <list>.Contains( <item> )`

```
var myProducts = from p in db.Products
                 where productList.Contains(p.ProductID)
                 select p;
```

Or you can have a list predefined as such:

```
int[] ids = {1, 2, 3};

var query = from item in context.items
            where ids.Contains( item.id )
            select item;
```

For the 'NOT' case, just add the '!' operator before the 'Contains' statement.

Comment: How do you handle if it's in a list? IN('a', 'b', 'c')

Comment: @DOK he just mentioned how you handle if it's in a list.

Comment: this only equal to in clause what is for not in

Comment: See my updated statement for the 'NOT' condition.  Essentially, you just need to add '!' before the Contains call.

Comment: For .NET Version 3.5 have a look at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexj/2009/03/25/tip-8-how-to-write-where-in-style-queries-using-linq-to-entities/

Answer (score 8):

I'm confused by your question. `in` and `not in` operate on fields in the query, yet you're not specifying a field in your example query. So it should be something like:

```
select * from table where fieldname in ('val1', 'val2')
```

or

```
select * from table where fieldname not in (1, 2)
```

The equivalent of *those* queries in LINQ to SQL would be something like this:

```
List<string> validValues = new List<string>() { "val1", "val2"};
var qry = from item in dataContext.TableName
          where validValues.Contains(item.FieldName)
          select item;
```

and this:

```
List<int> validValues = new List<int>() { 1, 2};
var qry = from item in dataContext.TableName
          where !validValues.Contains(item.FieldName)
          select item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This For ***SQL Not IN***

```
var v = from cs in context.Sal_Customer
         join sag in context.Sal_SalesAgreement
         on cs.CustomerCode equals sag.CustomerCode
         where
          !(
               from cus in context.Sal_Customer
               join
               cfc in context.Sal_CollectionFromCustomers
               on cus.CustomerCode equals cfc.CustomerCode
               where cus.UnitCode == locationCode &&
                     cus.Status == Helper.Active &&
                     cfc.CollectionType == Helper.CollectionTypeDRF
               select cus.CustomerCode
           ).Contains(cs.CustomerCode) &&
           cs.UnitCode == locationCode &&
           cs.Status == customerStatus &&
           SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Month", sag.AgreementDate, drfaDate) < 36
           select new CustomerDisasterRecoveryDetails
           {
             CustomerCode = cs.CustomerCode,
             CustomerName = cs.CustomerName,
             AgreementDate = sag.AgreementDate,
             AgreementDuration = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Month", sag.AgreementDate, drfaDate)
   };
```

Please Try This For ***SQL IN***

```
context.Sal_PackageOrItemCapacity.Where(c => c.ProjectCode == projectCode && c.Status == Helper.Active && c.CapacityFor.Contains(isForItemOrPackage)).ToList();
```