# LINQ to SQL - How to "Where ... in ..."

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to use linq to sort a resultset. The resultset should contain all items which has it's code also in the given array. To make this a bit clearer, in sql this should be:

```
select * from tblCodes where CodeSort in (0, 2, 3, 5, 6)
```

Now I want to do the same thing in LINQ but I can't seem to pull it off.. I've tried Contains, but that didn't give me the correct result (or I might have been using it wrong). I'm writing my code in VB.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this

```
Dim ids = {1, 2, 3}

Dim query = From item In context.items Where ids.Contains(item.id)item
```

[Linq to SQL in and not in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047657/linq-to-sql-in-and-not-in)

Comment: Okay, I was being silly. Seems it DID work, I was just checking the wrong values. Thanks for pointing out I was right anyways ;)