# Get the difference between two lists using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have two lists and I need to compare them and only return a List of Items not in both.

```
var listOfIds = new List<int> {1,2,4};

var persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>
{
    new Person {Id = 1, Name = "Person 1"},
    new Person {Id = 2, Name = "Person 2"},
    new Person {Id = 3, Name = "Person 3"},
    new Person {Id = 4, Name = "Person 4"}
};
```

In this example `new Person {Id = 3, Name = "Person 3"}` would be the result.
A Linq solution would be preferred.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

not in will work for you

```
var listOfIds = new List<int> {1,2,4};

var query = from item in persons 
            where !listOfIds .Contains( item.id )
            select item;
```

You can check for more detail : [SQL to LINQ ( Case 7 - Filter data by using IN and NOT IN clause)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047657/linq-to-sql-in-and-not-in)

Comment: Great Thanks, always forget how to do it :-)

Comment: There's a function for this, `Except`, which is not only cleaner, it's also faster.

Answer (score 40):

You can also use lambda:

```
var query = persons.Where(item => !listOfIds.Contains(item.Id));
```

Answer (score 28):

```
var list1 = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5};
var list2 = new List<int> {2,3,4,5,6};

list1.Except(list2); //1 - items removed
list2.Except(list1); //6 - items added
```

Answer (score 1):

With Linq in C# you can do the following variants which give the same results:

```
int[] numbers1 = { 1,2,3,4 };
int[] numbers2 = { 3,4,5,6 };

// Ac V Bc, thus complement of A plus the complement of B
IEnumerable<int> differencesVariant1 = 
numbers1.Except(numbers2).Union(numbers2.Except(numbers1));

// (A V b)c, thus complement of (set A plus set B)
IEnumerable<int> differencesVariant2 = 
numbers1.Union(numbers2).Except(numbers1.Intersect(numbers2));

Console.WriteLine("variant 1:");
foreach (int number in differencesVariant1)
    Console.WriteLine(number);   // prints: 1,2,5,6

Console.WriteLine("variant 2:");
foreach (int number in differencesVariant2)
    Console.WriteLine(number);   // prints: 1,2,5,6
```