# Compare two List of keyvaluepair

Tags: c#

I have two List

```
List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>> List1;
List<List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>> List2;
```

I want to get a List>> List3, Which is the differnce of List1 and List2.
Note: - Data is something like this:

List 1 -

```
         [{name, David},{eid,55},{sal,25}],
         [{name, Tina},{eid,56},{sal,20}],
         [{name, Bony},{eid,57},{sal,26}],
         [{name, Mahima},{eid,58},{sal,20}]
```

List 2 -

```
         [{name, David},{eid,55},{sal,25}],
         [{name, Tina},{eid,56},{sal,20}]
```

As in the above lists we can see that there are two elements in List1 which are not available in List2, I want to get the list of those element.

Expected output: 
List3 -

```
         [{name, Bony},{eid,57},{sal,26}],
         [{name, Mahima},{eid,58},{sal,20}]
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: This is probably been answered already. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7347402/706456)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between two lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5636438/difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: If you were to google "C# difference between lists", the second result is the question I marked this as a duplicate of. Please do *even some* research next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps one more idea.
It  is a list of a list of string keys and values, why not to use string comparison?

```
public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>
{
    public static readonly Comparer Default = new Comparer();
    private Comparer() { }

    private static string KvpToString(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp)
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Key) ? string.Empty : kvp.Key) + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Value) ? string.Empty : kvp.Value);
    }
    public bool Equals(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> x, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> y)
    {
        var xx = x.Select(KvpToString).Aggregate((c, n) => c + n);
        var yy = y.Select(KvpToString).Aggregate((c, n) => c + n);
        return string.Compare(xx, yy) == 0;
    }
    public int GetHashCode(List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

So in the end, all its needs is:

```
var list3 = list1.Except(list2, Comparer.Default);
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I copied previous version of Comparer, it was missing private constructor and Comparer.Default field. Now repaired...

Answer (score 2):

You can use this approach:

```
List<List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> List3 = List1
    .Where(l => !l.All(kv => List2.Any(l2 => l2.Contains(kv))))
    .ToList();
```

You can use `Contains` here because [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42(v=vs.110).aspx) is a value type. If it was a class you would have to use `Any` and compare each key and value with each other (or override `Equals`+`GetHashCode`).