# Visual C#, Find records in DataTable A which is or not in DataTable B

Tags: c#, linq, select, filter, datatable

Let's say both DataTable A and B has a column **ID**.

Is there any **concise** way using **Linq** (Not **for loop**) to find records in A which is (or not) in B base on ID!?

For example:

```
A
---
ID     Value
2        7
2        3
3        5
5        6
7        2
7        5
7        4

B
---
ID     Value
1        3
1        9
2        4
4        6
4        2
7        4
9        3

Results from A which is ALSO in B base on ID
---
ID     Value
2        7
2        3
7        2
7        5
7        4

Results from A which is NOT in B base on ID
---
ID     Value
3        5
5        6
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the difference between two lists using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347386/get-the-difference-between-two-lists-using-linq)

Comment: Thanks! Let me go see what I can do with it and update here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Any method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) may work for you.

Something like this, obviously variable depending on your data structure:

```
AInB = A.Where(a => B.Any(b => b.ID == a.ID));

ANotInB = A.Where(a => !B.Any(b => b.ID == a.ID));
```