# show all AD group members who are not in a table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, active-directory

How would i translate the following sql query to LINQ

```
select *
from groupprincipal.members 
where displayname not in (select adusername 
                          from employees)
```

I am wanting to list all members in an Active Directory group that are not in the employees table

I tried

```
var notLoggedIn = from groupMembers in groupPrincipal.Members
                          from loggedIn in employeeRepository.All
                          where groupMembers.DisplayName != loggedIn.ActiveDirectoryName
                          select groupMembers;
```

But as you will know it did not work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL in and not in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047657/linq-to-sql-in-and-not-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var notLoggedIn = from groupMembers in groupPrincipal.Members
                  where !employeeRepository.Select(p=> p.adUserName).Contains(groupMembers.DisplayName)
                  select groupMembers;
```

Comment: thank you, your solution DID work. My bad, i should have been comparing groupMembers.Name instead of groupMembers.DisplayName, its Friday :(

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do it:

```
var notLoggedIn = 
from groupMembers in groupPrincipal.Members
where !(from loggedIn in employeeRepository.All
        select loggedIn.ActiveDirectoryName).Contains(groupMembers.DisplayName)
select notLoggedIn;
```

Comment: sorry @Lister, did not work, select notLoggedIn throws a build error so does select loggedIn, select groupMembers returns all the groupMembers

Comment: thank you, your solution DID work. My bad, i should have been comparing groupMembers.Name instead of groupMembers.DisplayName, its Friday :(                                                                  However change Select notLoggedIn to Select groupMembers