# Passing a List of Strings to a where clause in a LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, list

I am working with a C# List on which I am performing some LINQ query in a C# windows application and I came across a situation where I have to pass a list of strings to a where clause in the LINQ query similar to `WHERE Product NOT IN ('sa','as')` in `SQL`, but I am not exactly sure how I can implement in LINQ and pass List of Strings to the query.

FOr a single parameter I am using the following code

```
 var hiddenProductList = recordsToProcess.Where(x => x.Product != product).ToList();
```

now I have a list named `listProducts` and I want to pass this to above query in `where` and get the results

**Is there any way I can implement this?**

Comment: Asked and answered already - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047657/linq-to-sql-in-and-not-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.Where(x => !listProducts.Contains(x.Product))
```