# How to use 'Sql in' with ASP.NET MVC repository pattern

Tags: c#, sql, repository-pattern

I have this SQL query :

```
select * 
from press 
where compId = 36 
  and categories in (1, 7, 21);
```

I tried to apply it in format of an ASP.NET MVC repository pattern:

```
 iPressRepository.GetAll().Where(x => (x.compId == 36)).ToList();
```

But my result is incorrect, because I missed categories 'in' in my second query. Is there a way to apply `IN` operator with a repository pattern?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL in and not in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047657/linq-to-sql-in-and-not-in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var categoriesToLookFor = new[] { 1, 7, 21 };
var press = iPressRepository.GetAll()
                            .Where(x => (x.compId == 36) && (categoriesToLookFor.Contains(x.categories)))
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but my 'categoriesToLookFor' is int field, so 'int does not contain a definition for.. like that error message

Comment: What do you mean "my `categoriesToLookFor`"? I thought the column in question on the database was named `categories`, based on your SQL query.

Comment: Can you please provide the entire error, and specify where it's going wrong?

Comment: It works Brother. Thanks a lot. My categories field was int?(nullable int). Then I change it to int. Then works. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I assume that should be something like this

```
iPressRepository.GetAll().Where(x => (x.compId == 36)&&(x.categories==1||x.categories==7||x.categories==21)).ToList();
```

Comment: This works but my categories comes dynamically. Then this query length may vary time to time. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If you use **GetAll()** you will get all data from SQL but you need just some data so you should use **AsQueryable()**

Repository :

```
public IQueryable<T> AsQueryable()
{
    return _entities.AsQueryable();
}
```

Controller :

```
var list = iPressRepository.AsQueryable()
        .Where(i => (new[] { 1, 7, 21 }).Contains(i.categories) && i.compId == 36).ToList();
```