# How can i get employees from department 10 which have a job which is also practiced in dept 30?

Tags: c#, linq

The question is: "*Get all employees from department 10 which have a job which is also practiced in dept 30*"

I want to do it in the non-ExtensionMethod format - like:

```
from e in emp
select e;
```

I tried something like that

```
var x =
    from e in emp
    where e.deptno == 10 && e.job == (from e2 in scott.emp
                                      where e2.deptno == 30
                                      select e2.job)
    select e;
```

which just makes sense that it doesn't work because i can't compare string with IEnumerable

So how can I solve this?

Comment: Use a [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-inner-joins)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey and what condition would i use?

Comment: @HereticMonkey i just have 1 table should i join from employees to employees?

Comment: You would join `emp` to `emp` on `job` and have one table limited to `deptno == 10` and the other to `deptno == 30`. I mean, this is just how I would think about it.

Comment: So `where e.deptno == 10` then  `join e2 in emp on e.job equals e2.job` and finally `where e2.deptno == 30` ?

Comment: Well if that's your idea, why not try it and see?

Comment: Alternatively with the query in your question, with the `e.job == (from`, the equals should be an `IN` clause (in standard SQL) - I think you express it a bit differently in linq though - try the suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047657/linq-to-sql-in-and-not-in perhaps

Comment: Just join, don't try and conditionally join.