# Why dynamic Linq does not work with .contains?

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating dynamic `query` for `linq` using `contains` but I am not getting any results back. Results exists in SQL.

What am I doing wrong here? Since I can have N values for columns, `.Contains` should be okay.

**Code:**

```
public IAsyncEnumerable<MyTable> GetMyTableRecordsPerFilter(
    IReadOnlyList<string> filters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
  
  var queryParams = generateQuery(filters);
  
  var query = _dbContext.Exception.AsNoTracking();

  if (queryParams.Result.ContainsKey("Location")) // (COL, NYC)
      query = query.Where(x => x.Location.Contains(queryParams.Result["Location"]));
      
  if (queryParams.Result.ContainsKey("StockNumber")) // ('1111150416', '2222250416', '6666650416')
      query = query.Where(x => x.StockNumber.ToString().Contains(queryParams.Result["StockNumber"]));

  var result = query.AsAsyncEnumerable(); // No results returned
  return result;
}
```

**SQL:**

[image]

Comment: do you want to search a list of values in a list?

Comment: Yeah. Right now I am getting `(COL, NYC)` but SQL expects `('COL', 'NYC')`. Would that be an issue?

Comment: I would not use that procedure or the answer suggested, I would use search a list inside a list. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047657/linq-to-sql-in-and-not-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the search condition and the target variable mixed up. For example, if your `Location` contains the string `NYC` and `queryParams.Result["Location"]` contains the string `(COL, NYC)`, then you need to first partition the string into a collection and then search whether the collection contains `Location` value:

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<MyTable> GetMyTableRecordsPerFilter(
    IReadOnlyList<string> filters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
{
    var queryParams = generateQuery(filters);
  
    var query = _dbContext.Exception.AsNoTracking();

    if (queryParams.Result.ContainsKey("Location")) // (COL, NYC)
    {
        var locations = queryParams
            .Result["Location"]
            .Trim('(', ')') // delete brackets if needed
            .Split(",") // split stinf by comma
            .Select(s => s.Trim()) // delete leading whitespaces 
            .ToArray();
        query = query.Where(x => locations.Contains(x.Location));
    }
      
    if (queryParams.Result.ContainsKey("StockNumber")) // ('1111150416', '2222250416', '6666650416')
    {
        var stockNumbers = queryParams
            .Result["StockNumber"]
            .Trim('(', ')') // delete brackets if needed
            .Split(",") // split stinf by comma
            .Select(s => s.Trim()) // delete leading whitespaces 
            .ToArray();
        query = query.Where(x => stockNumbers.Contains(x.StockNumber.ToString()));
    }

    var result = query.AsAsyncEnumerable();
    return result;
}
```